# Can I install Ubuntu on a PC that has a touch screen?

Tags: touchscreen

Specifically the HP ENVY TouchSmart All-in-One 20-d003la - All in one - 1 x Core i3 3220 / 3.3 GHz.

I mean, if the touch screen will recognize the 5 fingers?

Answer (score 1):

Try booting LiveUSB on it.
If it doesn't work, check if the touchscreen is listed there:

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-devices.html

You can also check info at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch , especially https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Testing that contains descriptions of tools to check multitouch devices. You can install them in the live session in the same way as on an installed system.